Do Matrices Representing the Same Linear Transformation in Different Bases Share the Same Eigenvalues?
Consider two bases e and e' in a vector space. Let A be a matrix representing a linear transformation with respect to the basis e, and let A' be the matrix representing the same linear transformation with respect to the basis e'. Are the eigenvalues of A and A' identical?

What have you tried so far? Where did you get the problem?
